# 2009 Kia Rio hatchback radio not working after battery replacement

Tags: kia, audio

I drive a 2009 Kia Rio Hatchback. A few days ago the car battery was replaced and I can't get the **K100R radio** to work.

Last time my car lost power and was jump-started, I was able to input a 4-digit code to unlock the radio (so I know the code is correct). This time, it won't accept the code and just displays "*CD1*".

I don't know what this means. What can I do to make it work again?

Comment: Hi can I ask what your codes were? I'm having trouble finding mine after changing my battery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally managed to solve this problem. There were two, *different* 4-digit codes: one on the back of the manual, and another on a separate card. The 4-digit code on the card was the correct one for the radio.

Answer (score 0):

After trying many unlock codes using the 1212 theory to no luck.

I got a bar code reader and used first 4 digits of the bar code